# Visual Studio ASP.NET Core 1.0 project can't compile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Help. I can't compile my project from VS 2015, apparently something went wrong when installed/uninstalled of the project packages with NuGET.

Every time I want to build, I get the following errors:

> Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'dependencies',
>   line 60, position 0.  AutorizarCreditoApp C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets
>   262

And

> Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'dependencies',
>   line 60, position 0.  AutorizarCreditoApp C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets 262

NuGET packages cannot restore anything, so I'm stuck and the project is messed up. I just watch the files, at the current lines, but it doesn't any sense to me, for example Microsoft.Dot.Net.Common.Targets complains at the beginning of this:

```
<Dnx
      RuntimeExe="$(SDKToolingExe)"
      Condition="'$(_DesignTimeHostBuild)' != 'true'"
      ProjectFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
      Arguments="$(_BuildArguments)"
      />
```

And, project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0",
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",

    "tools": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },

    "frameworks": {
      "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
          "dotnet5.6",
          "portable-net45+win8"
        ]
      }
    },

    "buildOptions": {
      "emitEntryPoint": true,
      "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },

    "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
        "System.GC.Server": true
      }
    },

    "publishOptions": {
      "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
      ]
    },

    "scripts": {
      "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:
After adding a } character to the project.json character I tried to compile it again.

After that now the errors are the following:

> Unable to find project.json in
>   'C:_Fuentes\AutorizarCreditoApp\src\AutorizarCreditoApp'
>
> 'C:_Fuentes\AutorizarCreditoApp\src\AutorizarCreditoApp\project.json'
>   does not have any frameworks listed in the 'frameworks'
>   section.  AutorizarCreditoApp C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets 262

Comment: Your `project.json` is not valid json. One `}` is missing. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: As I already say, even if I fix it, the problem changes. When I hit build the project is unable to find project.json

Comment: So what is the point to post invalid structure?

Comment: Just posted a solution for that.
Please have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623445/microsoft-dotnet-common-targets262-5-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-i/43742153#43742153http://)

Comment: Just posted a solution here [Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623445/microsoft-dotnet-common-targets262-5-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-i/43742153#43742153)

Answer (score 0):

Check your reference in the project for dependency,if reference is ok then reinstall package from nuget after uninstalling>close VS>open VS

Comment: References are not okay. It says References (Errors - see Error List)

Comment: go to solution explorer>References> remove the exclamation reference and then left click,if you have references then add it manually otherwise use nuget package .I suggest Use manual as you ll get confirm what is missing next

Comment: The problem is there is not References listed, and I can't restore them with Nuget

Comment: Thanks. The only way to fix it was Discarding changes to that file with Git.

Comment: It was not a problem of git, but it helped me to resolve it by reverting the project.json file to the last commit. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after uninstalling a nuget package.
I use the nuget package manager to install and uninstall packages.

I found the fault was in my project.json file, a closing } went missing after restore failed.

Found that my dependencies was missing a closing tag just before the start of tools.